# How to make listview scroll move on to new data added in android

Tags: android

I am develoing an app in which I sent server request and in response server send me data which was then added in listview, Scenario is something like that Initially 5 data are visible to user and when I scroll to end of listview app send server request and in response server send me 5 more data what I want listview scroll to the new data which was added in listview.For this i already user listview.setSelection(listview.getCount() - 1); but this will scroll listview to the end of data.

Comment: Well the question is, does this data get appended to the end or somewhere in the middle? If it gets appended to the end, you should change that to `listview.scrollToPosition(listview.getCount() - 6);` (because you want your last 5 visible.)

Comment: Have a look at it  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

Listview has a method for scrolling to position:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(YOUR_POSITION);
```

Just save your items count before making a request and then scroll to that position+1.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                listView.setSelection(listView.getCount() - (no. of new items added  + 1));
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: this will move listview scroll to the end of data ,but I want if 5 new data are added then listview scroll must be on the 1st of 5 data which was added

Comment: then instead of `listView.getCount() - 1` do `listView.getCount() - (no. of new items added + 1)`

Comment: suppose initally 5 data are there in listview and 5 more data are added then I want listview scroll to move on 6th index....same like when data increment next time suppose 3 more data are added then listview scroll must be on 11th......

Answer (score 0):

It depends how are you adding data in listView. I am assuming you are using some similar method for this in your adapter.

```
List<POJO> items;
void addData(List<POJO> data)
{
  for(POJO p: data){
    items.add(p);
  }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
istView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                listView.setSelection(items.size()-data.size());
                            }
                    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

However, you are getting the response from server add that item to the ArrayList which you are adding to Adapter. After adding items to the ArrayList save its size - 1 to an integer variable and call notifyDataSetChanged. Now whenever you get a new response then scroll your listview to the stored variable position + 1, it will take scroll point at exact where you want.

Note: If in case you didn't get any response then don't scroll to position + 1, it will give issue for you.

e.g.

```
//By default
int scrollToPosition = 0;
```

//After webservice response data is added to your array list.

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.setSelection(scrollToPosition+1);//For direct scroll or
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollToPosition+1);//For smooth scroll
scrollToPosition = list.size() - 1;
```